# How to save an image (input type="file") into the local storage and display it back onload of a page in javaScript

Tags: javascript, image, local-storage

I have an input type file and when I click, it will select a particular image, likewise some other input type text which i have to use to collect data from the user and I am as well having a button to set the data into the localStorage once the button is clicked.

Onload of the page, I want the information on the localStorage (productImg, productName, productOldPrice, productCategory, productNewPrice, productSavePrice) to display on the browser.

Note: Every other information are displaying except the productImg which is why am asking this question.
What I wanted to archive is a way of setting each product image into the localStorage and when displaying it on the browser, each product image should be display on the designated place.

> ```
> <button id="adminSponsorPush" class="btn btn-lg btn-success " style="width: 30%;" onclick="text()">Sponsored Products</button>
> <input type="file" id="adminDealImg">
> <input type="text" name="" id="adminDealName" placeholder="Product Name">
> <input type="text" name="" id="adminOldPrice" placeholder="deals Old Price">
> <input type="text" name="" id="adminNewPrice" placeholder="deals new Price">
> <button type="button" onclick="setIt()" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
> <div id="todaysDeal" class="d-flex flex-wrap w-100 gap-3 p-2 border border-danger border-2"></div>
> ```

This is the JavaScript code that set the data into the localStorage

```js
let allProducts = [];
if (localStorage.companyProduct) {
  allProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("companyProduct"));
}

text = () => {
  let products = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    password: "",
    topDeal: [],
    sponsorProduct: [],
    recommendedProduct: [],
    inspiredProduct: [],
    laptops: [],
    smartPhone: [],
    healthBeauty: [],
    groceries: [],
    videoGames: [],
    mobileAccessories: [],
    homeFurnishings: [],
    fitnessToolsEquipment: [],
    kidsWearAccessories: [],
    topDealOnTelevision: [],
  };

  allProducts.push(products);
  localStorage.setItem("companyProduct", JSON.stringify(allProducts));

};

setIt = () => {
  for (let index = 0; index < allProducts.length; index++) {
    let topDealProduct = {
      productImg: adminDealImg.value,
      productName: adminDealName.value,
      productOldPrice: adminOldPrice.value,
      productCategory: `product`,
      productNewPrice: adminNewPrice.value,
      productSavePrice: `You save ₦${adminOldPrice.value - adminNewPrice.value}`,
    };
    allProducts[index].topDeal.push(topDealProduct);
    localStorage.setItem("companyProduct", JSON.stringify(allProducts));
    localStorage.setItem("currentUserIndex", index);
  }
};
```

This is the javaScript code that will display the information into the browser when the page is load

```js
currentProductIndex = localStorage.getItem("currentUserIndex");

displayProducts = () => {
  todaysDeal.innerHTML = "";
  eachTopDealProduct = allProducts[currentProductIndex].topDeal;
  for (let index = 0; index < eachTopDealProduct.length; index++) {
    todaysDeal.innerHTML += `
  <div onclick="topDealProductPage(${index})" class="d-flex p-3 shadow each-todays-deal gap-3"
  style="width: 32.5%; height: 120px; cursor: pointer;"
>
<img src="${eachTopDealProduct[index].productImg}" alt="" id="dealsImg"/>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
    <div class="text-capitalize" id="dealsProductName">${eachTopDealProduct[index].productName}</div>
    <div class="">
      <div class="d-flex gap-2">
      
      <div class="fw-bold fs-4" id="dealsPrice">₦${eachTopDealProduct[index].productNewPrice}</div>
      <div class="fw-bold fs-6 my-auto text-decoration-line-through text-secondary" id="dealsPrice">₦${eachTopDealProduct[index].productOldPrice}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="fw-bold" style="font-size: 12px; color: #33B27B;" id="dealsSave">${eachTopDealProduct[index].productSavePrice}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
        `;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get file data from onChange callback and transfer it to base64, then set base64 to LocalStorage.

```
<input type="file" id="adminDealImg"> 
<img src="" id="img" alt="">
<script>
  if(localStorage.getItem('img-BASE64')){
    document.querySelector('#img').src=localStorage.getItem('img-BASE64')
  }
  function getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
      resolve(reader.result)
    };
    reader.onerror = reject
    })
  }
  document.querySelector('#adminDealImg').addEventListener('change', async(e)=>{
    const data = await getBase64(e.target.files[0])
    localStorage.setItem('img-BASE64', data)
  })
</script>
```

---

After you have changed the question.

Set img data to localStorage is different from normal data.

```
// error here 
productImg: adminDealImg.value,
```

you can set image base64 data as a unique key and get it by this key as identity, maybe email ?

```
LocalStorage.setItem(img-Base64-${email}, 'sth base64')
```

Please click LIKE button. Orz....

Comment: Useful click Please. Orz.

Comment: What you did really works perfect but what of in a situation whereby i need to save different user data into the local Storage and not just the image alone. E.g. If i need to save their names, phone number, etc. in an array of object which also have another array. I will edit the question so you can get what i wanted to archive. Check the new edited question. Thanks

Comment: As base64 is a simple string data, LocalStorage only accept string. 
If you want to store a lot of data  like array base on a key ,you may need JSON.stringify to transfer array object to string and set it to localStorage.

Comment: I have edited the question to what i wanted to archive, you can help me check and if there is any help you can render, i will really appreciate it. Am just learning JavaScript and i know how to set other information into the localStorage except images. Thanks

Comment: Set img data to localStorage is different from normal data. 
```
// error here
productImg: adminDealImg.value,
```
you can set image base64 data as a unique key and get it by this key as identity.
```
LocalStorage.setItem(`img-Base64-${email}`, 'sth stuff')
```

Please click LIKE button.   Orz....

Comment: I still cant understand how you explain it. Is there anything you can help me do to it?